# aws datapipeline: waiting for dependencies

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a datapipe that gets stuck and goes in pending mode, everytime "Waiting on dependencies".

Here I am using "Hive Activity", which needs an input and output. In my case, all my data is in the hadoop infrastructure and thus I really don't need S3 Input and S3 output. However, there is no way to remove them, as datapipeline errors out. Further, the pipe gets stuck at this point, inspite of a precondition that S3 node "exists". Every time I run this pipe I have to manually "markfinish" the S3node, things work after that.

```
{
   Name:
   @S3node1_2014-08-01T13:59:50
   [View instance fields]
   Description:
   Status: WAITING_ON_DEPENDENCIES
   Waiting on:
   @RunExpertCategories_2014-08-01T13:59:50
}
```

Any insights would help. AWS Datapipeline documentation does not go into detail.

Comment: Did you figure this out? What kind of solution can one apply?

Answer (score 0):

If you set `"stage": "false"` on the [HiveActivity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-hiveactivity.html) then the input and output nodes will not be required.